# A way to set zoom limit in google_map in googleway library

Tags: max, zooming, googleway

my problem is simple. Need to set max zoom in the google_map object from gooleway package.

I need that to protect privacy. So I need to find some way to disallow user to keep zooming data to single observations.

Have you got any ideas?

Regards